# Vaadin @CssImport not working in jar dependency

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

I can't seem to get the @CssImport annotation working when the component class is in a separate jar. (Main web project is Vaadin 18)

I checked out the addon starter:

https://github.com/vaadin/addon-starter-flow

And adjusted the TheAddon class to add a css class name:

```
@CssImport("./theaddon.css")
public class TheAddon extends Div {

    public TheAddon() {
        setText("Hello");
        addClassName("theaddon");
        
    }
}
```

I then added the theaddon.css file to:

```
src\main\resources\META-INF\resources\frontend\theaddon.css
```

With the styles:

```
.theaddon {
    color:Red;
}
```

However when I use the addon, I do not see the style applied. I *do* see the style if I extend the TheAddon class within my web project. So this leads me to believe there's some classpath magic that isn't happening correctly.

Comment: Are you using Vaadin 23.0.0, if yes, there is a fix in 23.0.1.

Comment: @TatuLund My web app is v 18.0.2. Do you have a link to the issue/fix?

Comment: Vaadin 18 is no longer supported and it is very old, you should not use it anymore. You have probably a different bug. I just know that there was such bug in 23.0.0, which is fixed in 23.0.1. I have done several add-ons using CssImport and not noticed this kind of issue e.g. with versions 20 - 22.

Comment: https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/13211

Comment: @TatuLund I'm now trying to upgrade to v23 but now running into issues with getting the front-end built. So that doesn't really help much for right now.

Comment: @TatuLund I got the webapp working under vaadin 23, but that didn't fix the issue. The styles from the dependent jar are still not present. So this doesn't seem to have anything to do with v18.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Argh - the issue was that the vaadin.whitelisted-packages property was set. Thus Vaadin was not scanning / finding the components when building the front-end. Correcting this property fixed it.